# Ruby: Sub is not substituting my string after reading file / Encoding wrong?

Tags: ruby, string, file, encoding, utf-16

I am completely new to programming and worked through some ruby tutorials in the last weeks. I need a program to replace a few words in about 600 files.
At the moment I am stuck at using sub and gsub to change the words in the variable I read from the specific file.

```
My code looks like this:

Dir.glob("items/**/*.dat") do |item_dat_file| 
  puts "working on: " + item_dat_file + " ... "
  puts
  text_full = File.read(item_dat_file)

  puts text_full
  text_full.sub!('[UNIT]', "TESTIT")
  puts text_full
```

Unfortunetely both outputs of the variable text_full are the same, nothing gets replaced.

```
 [ U N I T] #=> should be changed
...
 [ / U N I T ]
```

I am reading the file from utf-16 Little Endian encoding (that is what the game to which the files belong is giving me). Could this be the problem? Because after reading it into the ruby variable there are spaces added between all the characters. And Ruby tells me for item_dat_file.encoding, the file was UTF-8.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I found a hint on opening UTF-16 files with ruby. I changed the code:

```
Dir.glob("items/**/*.dat") do |item_dat_file|
  puts "working on: " + item_dat_file + " ... "
  text_full = File.open(item_dat_file, "rb:UTF-16LE:UTF-8").read
  puts text_full.sub("UNIT", "TESTIT")
  puts text_full
end
```

Now the printed text is fine, no more additional space characters. But how do I reverse this, when writing back to the file? It should have UTF-16 again in the end.

EDIT2:

This is my solution for my initial question.

```
Dir.glob("items/**/*.dat") do |item_dat_file|
  puts "working on: " + item_dat_file + " ... "
  text_full = File.open(item_dat_file, "r:UTF-16LE:UTF-8").read
  text_full.sub!("UNIT", "TESTIT")
  puts text_full
  File.open(item_dat_file, "w:UTF-16LE").write text_full
end
```

Works as expected. THX alot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the input/output doesn't actually have spaces in [UNIT]. If it does, you'll need to add them to your pattern to be replaced.

The difference between sub and gsub is that gsub will replace all matching patterns throughout the text, while sub will just do the first.

Here's a quick test from IRB showing the difference:

```
irb(main):013:0> s = '[UNIT]
irb(main):014:0'
irb(main):015:0' blah
irb(main):016:0'
irb(main):017:0' [UNIT];
irb(main):018:0' '
=> "[UNIT]\n\nblah\n\n[UNIT];\n"

irb(main):021:0> print s.sub('[UNIT]', 'TESTIT')
TESTIT

blah

[UNIT];
=> nil

irb(main):022:0> print s.gsub('[UNIT]', 'TESTIT')
TESTIT

blah

TESTIT;
=> nil
```

EDIT: If you're on Unix/Linux, or have GNU-like tools on your system, you could do this in one line via find/grep/sed, like so:

```
find . -print | grep -i "items/.*/*.dat" | xargs sed "s/\[UINT\]/TESTIT/gi"
```

This will actually print out the changed files to the command line. If they look good, and you want to actually overwrite them, add "-i" as a parameter to the sed command.

EDIT: OK, you were absolutely correct, it's an encoding issue, so the two-byte character encodings were what was causing the string mismatch and the spaces when printing. I couldn't extract the .adm files on OSX, so I downloaded a mod and tried with the .dat files in that, and came up with the following:

```
# encoding: utf-8
Dir.glob("*.dat") do |item_dat_file| 
    puts "working on: " + item_dat_file + " ... "
    fd = File.open(item_dat_file, "rb:UTF-16LE")

    text_full = fd.read().encode("UTF-8")

    puts text_full
    text_full.gsub!("[OBJECT]", "TESTIT")
    puts text_full
end
```

Basically, you open the file as UTF-16LE, read it, then encode it as UTF-8. Modify that like you want to, then when you have to write it back, you can call:

```
text_full.encode("UTF-16LE")
```

and write that to the file. This example doesn't handle writing back to the file, but it shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello, sorry, but I copied the UNIT Tags from the cmd.exe output, which added spaces after each letter. the original text file does not have them - could it be an encoding problem? Or why are the spaces added when the variable is printed to the screen? I was aware of sub and gsub differences, I just wanted to test sub, if it would do anything at all. thx

Comment: Not sure if encoding would be an issue, but it's not impossible. There could be zero-width space characters in there, the brackets around UNIT could be other Unicode characters that just look like [], but really aren't. What do you get if you print text_full.index("[UNIT]")?

Comment: Hy, it seems like nil, getting just an empty line... But if I let it print text_full to cmd, I get the complete file content (it is more than the UNIT Tag, I just left the rest out for keeping the post short), just with the spaces between all the letters and signs. So it can read the file, but where are all the spaces coming from

Comment: [link](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) It looks like my problem could be a conflict between source encoding and the string's encoding.

Comment: Try the command-line script I just added, see if that works. If it does, it might not be the encoding. Which game is it, if I might ask?

Comment: if I ask for the .dat file's encoding with file.encoding, ruby tells me it is UTF-8 (same as ruby standard source code encoding, according to my link), but my text editor tells me the file is utf-16le.
Game is called Torchlight.
did a sub replacement in a small rb script and it worked like yours above...

Comment: Ahh, great game. Have you checked the Runic forums? Lots of tools available there for modding, some with source. They've probably already figured out the problem. In any case, I'll install it on Steam tonight so I can actually play with the .DAT files and try to figure out the problem.

Comment: or I could just install it on my Macbook here at work with the ultra-fast connection.

Comment: Hello,
I could not find any source codes for the two item changer tools that are available from the community. Problem with them is, that one of them crashes and the other is not doing all the things I need reagarding the text changes. And the sources won't be in Ruby, which is the only language I understand at least a bit. I think it is an encoding problem. But if ruby is reading it already as utf-8, I don't know how to change that... as said, sub works in a normal ruby script with no external file usage. As a workaround I could use the spaced out versions as search patterns.

Comment: @CQu: Yup, it was encoding. This last update appears to work on my system, but you'll need to re-encode it back before writing out to the file. Also, you'll want to change the glob path, since I had to change it for use in a mod's directory.

Comment: Hy, thx, I already had the encoding added to my first post. Little bit different approach. I have the path issue already worked out, the code I posted here ist just a test snippet.

Comment: I already tried the re encoding after the sub work, but I get an error, because the writing is not working, it says something about ASCII not compatible with UTF-16LE....

Comment: Looks like you got it figured out. I have TL2, but haven't played it yet. Damn Steam sales have pushed my unplayed pile into the triple digits, and then there's Skyrim.

Comment: i hear you. Steam knows how to sell. I can't find any way to communicate via PN here on the site, I could add you in Steam, if you'd like, but don't know how to get the information across.